# Swift: ARKit TimeInterval to Date

Tags: swift, date, timestamp, arkit

The `currentFrame` (`ARFrame`) of `ARSession` has a `timestamp` attribute of type `TimeInterval` which represents the uptime at the moment the frame has been captured.

I need to convert this `TimeInterval` to the current time domain of the device.

If my assumption about `timestamp` is correct, adding the kernel BootTime and `timestamp` together would give me the correct date.

**Problem:** Adding the kernel BootTime and `timestamp` together gives me an Date that is not correct. (depending on the device`s last boot time up to 2 days variance)

**Current Code:**

```
func kernelBootTime() -> Date {
    var mib = [CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME]
    var bootTime = timeval()
    var bootTimeSize = MemoryLayout<timeval>.stride

    if sysctl(&mib, UInt32(mib.count), &bootTime, &bootTimeSize, nil, 0) != 0 {
        fatalError("Could not get boot time, errno: \(errno)")
    }

    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(bootTime.tv_sec) + Double(bootTime.tv_usec) / 1_000_000.0)
}

public func checkTime(_ session: ARSession) {
    guard let frame = session.currentFrame else { return }
    print(Date(timeInterval: frame.timestamp, since: kernelBootTime()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
var refDate = Date.now - ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime
```

gives you the date of the last device restart

```
public func checkTime(_ session: ARSession) {
    guard let frame = session.currentFrame else { return }
    print(Date(timeInterval: frame.timestamp, since: refDate))
}
```

prints the exact time when the image was taken. (in UTC time)